# Managing statuses and validation rules using state and factory design patterns

Tags: c#, validation, state-pattern, static-factory

In my recent project i have an `Order` class that its properties will be complete step by step by different users, and each user refer the partial completed order to next user(s), so i assume each `Order` has a `Status` at each time, for example when an `Order` creates, its `Status` will be `NewStatus`, when BOM(Bill of material) specified for it, its `Status` will be `BOMAttachedStatus`, when it planned for production its `Status` will be `PlannedStatus`, and so on.
[image]

Also i need apply some validation rules in each step to the `Order`, e.g user must specify customer name when create an `Order`(`NewState`), or user must set PlanningDate when `Order` is planning(`PlannedStatus`), ...

So, i decided to use **State Design Pattern** to manage states, and also use **Factory Design Pattern** to check validations:

[image]

```
public static class StatusFactory
{
    static public IStatus CreateOrderStatus(Order order)
    {
            //check statuses from last to first   
            if (order.PlanningDate != null)    
               return new PlannedStatus();
               ....            
            if(order.CustomerName != string.Empty)  
               return new OrderItemNewState();
    }
}
```

and when i want to save my `currentOrder`, i call `StateFactory.CreateOrderStatus(currentOrder)` to set its `Status`:

```
public void Save(Order order)
{
   order.Status = StatusFactory.CreateOrderStatus(order);
   UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is this method correct for my case? is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work, however you have some issues with your design and what you described.

1. In transitioning to each state rules need to be fired and validate input object - your design does not cover this
2. State changing is not managed anywhere so you are going to scatter that logic in your StateFacotry or elsewhere and handle it manually.

What I would to is creating a StateMachine class that you can simply call Transition method and provide a target State.
The transition method queries from State to know what rules need to be validated and calls validation method. If successful then it changes the state of object.

Benefit of this design:

1. StateMachine can register a graph of state (S1->S2,S3 | S2->END |    S3->S4 | S4->END)
2. State transitioning happens automatically based on register graph and
3. Each State knows what are the required rules to be met to allow the transition happens successfully. (Self-descriptive)
4. StateMachine has not exposed the logic how the states are transitioning and all encapsulated in that implementation
5. StateMAchine is independent of what the actual object is and manages all the transition logic plus validation execution (that you can simply integrate a full-fledged validation engine into your state machine)